# Teaching microsoft cognitive image recognition

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'd like to be able to teach the azure cognitive services image analyzer about specific objects and details about those objects.

Is there anyway to do that? Or does anyone know of any plans to enable developers to be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

training or using custom images isn't yet available for Computer Vision.  They often refer to it as domain specific models.  I know they have this on their feedback forum as [an enhancement request](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/356325-apis/suggestions/13289049-train-the-vision-api-with-custom-tags-domain-speci).  Go vote for it, I did!